# Return <td> value via onclick()

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, html-table

Using JavaScript, I have a table being built dynamically.  Within each `tr`, I have 2 `td` elements.  The first `td` is always a red X.  I want to be able to identify the value within the 2nd `td` when clicking the red X.

The value in the 2nd `td` is denoted below by `jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL[i].POS`.  Currently, when clicking the red X on any row, it is returning the same `POS` value; it's always returning the first value in that array.

```
for (var i = 0; i < jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL_CNT;i++) {
    surgViewTable2 += "<tr>"  
                   + "<td class='btn red delsave'"
                   + "onclick='alert(jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL[i].POS)'>"
                   + "X</td>"

                   + "<td class='labCol1'>"
                   +  jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL[i].POS
                   +  "</td>"

                   +  "<td class='hidden'></td>"
                   +  "</tr>"
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code? Because if so, you are missing a double quote before `X</td>"` . Also, in the alert, are you trying to execute `jsonPos.POS.RES...` or you just want to print the actual value when building the html?

Comment: Thanks Nadir....it was a formatting mistake on this site.  I appreciate the heads up though.  Can you help me setting / getting an attribute of <td> so that I can pass it to a function?
 $("td.hidden").attr("value",jsonPos.POS.SURG_QUAL[i].POS_CD);

Would this work?

Comment: That would set the an attribute with the same value in all `td.hidden`.

Comment: Sorry I am new to Javascript....I just want to set each <td> value differently depending on whats in my array at that point.  HOw would I do that?

Comment: If the order in the array is the same as the order in the appearance: `var z = 0; var tds = $('yourtableselector').find('td'); for(var i in tds) { tds[i].attr('value', jsonPos.POS.SURG_QUAL[z].POS_CD); z++; }`

Comment: Would that whole snippet go within my FOR loop or outside of it?  It looks like you already have an embedded FOR so it confused me a bit.

Comment: You wouldn't use your other loop, just the one I posted in the comment

Comment: @Nadir sorry for all the questions, but how would I integrate your code snippet above so that onclick() in the TD allows me to send the '....POS_CD' value to another function?  Thats really all I am looking to do.  The above alert() was just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Nadir would you mind explaining that code segment to me?  I don't understand how it would replace my above FOR( ) loop because all that is doing is generating my table.  Is this something that should be implanted after the above FOR () loop?  If so, where can I then call the onclick() event upon clicking the <td class='btn red delsave'> element?

Comment: here you go https://jsfiddle.net/9sfd48ge/

Answer (score 0):

`jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL[i].POS` may not be in window scope which is why this variable `jsonPos` may not be in available when user click on this `td`

You can directly take value in next column after it has been rendered.

replace

```
"onclick='alert(jsonPos.POS.RES_QUAL[i].POS)'>"
```

by

```
"onclick='alert(this.nextSibling.innerHTML)'>"
```

Also, you next line doesn't have the valid syntax, it is missing a double quote.

It should be

```
+ "X</td>"
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, that works well!  The double-quote miss was just an issue w/ editting on this site....thanks for pointing that out though!

So what Im really trying to do w/ the onclick(), is to call a function and pass a value from the jsonPos element into the function so that I can delete it from the custom table.  The value I want to pass is not the literal string but the code_value behind the scenes.  Do you know how I can reference this value with a similar method you are proposing?   If what I am saying confuses you just let me know.  I really appreciate the help!

Comment: @Will glad to help, Accept and upvote the best answer that has helped you http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: @Will you need to put the value you want to fetch in some attribute of `td` and fetch it later using `getAttribute` method

Comment: thanks for the advice.  Any hints at how I would do this?  I am very new to Javascript.  Basically just learning on the fly.

I tried putting the JSON element into a new <td> that I made hidden within my CSS but it seems as though the value is not being passed in there properly.

Comment: Is this setting the attr properly?
 $("td.hidden").attr("value",jsonPos.POS.SURG_QUAL[i].POS_CD);

Comment: @Will this looks fine

Comment: Will it set unique values for each hidden TD or will that statement set the same value for each hidden TD?

Comment: @Will I think your original question has been answered. For different problems, you need to raise different questions so that other experts also get the opportunity to answer them.